# Error in Model-less Checkbox in Yii framework PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, yii

Good Day.

I want to ask for your help. Regarding PHP Yii.

I have this model-less checkboxes on my controller.

**VIEW:**

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <?php echo CHtml::checkBox('Score[personal]', true, array()); ?>
  <label>Personal Details </label>
  <br><?php echo CHtml::checkBox('Score[prof]', true, array()); ?>
    <label>Professional Details </label>
    <br><?php echo CHtml::checkBox('Score[exam]', true, array()); ?>
      <label>Exam task and skills </label>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```js
if($attrs['personal'] == '1')
  $a= 1
if($attrs['prof'] == '1')
  $a=2
 if($attrs['exam'] == '1')
  $a=3
```

But I'm having this error.

"Undefined index: personal"

Can you help me on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be avoided with the help of `isset()`:

```
if (isset(Score['personal'])) 
{ 
// do something 
} 
// do something else if not set
```